# recursively searching bst for non-key value

Tags: c, search, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm having trouble with the logic of this.  How do I search the entire tree (since I can't rely on any order search) and only return one matching value (if it exists)?  If I return the recursive call, won't it fail once it hits the first leaf and hasn't found a match?

When using the function below, calls are made until a match is found or the end of the tree is reached, and the left-most node is returned regardless of matches.

My recursive function, traversing in-order:

```
tnode *find(tnode *ptr, const char *str)
{
    if (ptr == NULL) return ;

    if(strcmp (str,ptr->str) == 0)
        return ptr;


    else 
    {
        //search left subtree
        if (ptr->left != NULL)
            find(ptr->left, str) ;


        // search right subtree
        if (ptr->right != NULL)
            find(ptr->right, str) ;
    }

   return;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the left-subtree find returns non-NULL, you have a match and should return it. Currently you don't even look to see if it found anything.

If it *didn't* find anything, you can return the result of the right-subtree find (if it's NULL, you looked everywhere and didn't find anything).

```
tnode *find(tnode *ptr, const char *str)
{
    ptr *found;

    if (ptr == NULL) return NULL; /* nothing to see here */

    if(strcmp (str,ptr->str) == 0)
        return ptr; /* it is here! */

    /* try left subtree */
    found = find(ptr->left, str);
    if (found) return found; /* it was on the left */

    /* try right subtree */
    return find(ptr->right, str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first:

```
if (ptr == NULL) return ;
```

You supposed to return a value  according to the function prototype (`tnode *find(tnode *ptr, const char *str)`).

The second:

```
find(ptr->right, str);
```

You do not use the return value, so anyway result will be incorrect.

The third:

```
return;
```

The same as the first.

If you will fix all of it, it supposed to work.

BTW `if (ptr->left != NULL)` is not necessary, as you are checking `ptr == 0` at the beginning of the function.

The last one **please pay attention to compiler warnings**.

Comment: without the null checks I get a thrown exception (access violation reading 0xcccccccc)

Comment: @user2081737 seems to be a bit strange as `0xcccccccc` is not `NULL` anyway. Are you sure that you filled the tree correctly?

Comment: I must have been doing something stupid wrong, now that I try it again it works.

Comment: @user2081737 , if you are not filling pointer correctly, so you can get **undefined behavior**, so there is no guarantee that program will work the next time.